# can I use simpy(Python simulation library) in C?

Tags: c, simpy

I was assigned project that make operation system scheduling program in `C` and show simulation result in university.

I want to use `simpy` so that find out how to use `python` in `C`.
but I'm not sure `simpy` work in `C` because it looks like `python` work in `C`, just low-level.

can I use `simpy` in `C`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Comment: have you heard of cython?